# Pubnub userlist wont appear when published to github but works fine in adobe brackets

Tags: javascript, pubnub

The code below works fine when I use the IDE brackets. However, when I publish it on github it won't correctly connect to PubNub. I'm guessing that I don't have the SDK properly setup but I'm a bit of a noob at this and have run out of ideas on how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>LupkerMusic</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/console.css">


</head>
<body>

    <h1 class="title">LUPKERMUSIC<img src="lupkermusiclogoinverse.png"  
    style="width:50px;height:50;"></h1>

<p>List of Users</p>
<br>

<div id="channelStateBar" class="channelState"></div>
<br>

<button class="btn btn-primary updateButton" 
onclick="updateChannelState()">Update User List</button>

<script src=https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var publish_key = 'pub-c-a4dc5ebf-redacted';
        var subscribe_key = 'sub-c-1a1f6598-redacted';
         ssl: true;
        var username = window.location.search.substring(1).split('=')
[1];
        pubnub =PUBNUB.init({
            publish_key : publish_key,
            subscribe_key : subscribe_key,
            uuid : username

        });
    })();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateChannelState() {
        pubnub.here_now({
            channel : 'lupkschat',
            withPresence: true,
            callback : function(m){ debugger;
                $('#channelStateBar')[0].innerHTML = 
                'Occupancy : ' + m.occupancy + '<br/><br/><br/>' + 
 'Users : ' + m.uuids;
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *IDE brackets* and *publishing on github*?

Comment: [Use latest SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) and not a 3x version. https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.5.0.min.js - this will mean changes to your code too. More to come...

Comment: Will provide updated code very soon.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate it, that has been driving me nuts. Thanks again!

Comment: Cheers - if the answer below is solution, give it the up vote.

Answer (score 0):

## Parsing PubNub Here Now Results

I have updated your code to [PubNub SDK 4.5.0 (the latest at this post)](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk). And made proper adjustments to the code to ensure you get results, like subscribing to the channel so there is at least one occupant. But you could subscribe to the channel from other clients like in [your PubNub Admin Dashboard's Debug Console](https://admin.pubnub.com) or the [PubNub Dev Console](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/console).

In the 4x PubNub SDKs, the [hereNow results are presented in a much more rick format](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/presence#gobal_here_now) with multiple channels and uuids per channel, as follows:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    "payload": {
        "channels": {
            "81d8d989-b95f-443c-a726-04fac323b331": {
                "uuids": [
                    "70fc1140-22b5-4abc-85b2-ff8c17b24d59"
                ],
                "occupancy": 1
            },
            "81b7a746-d153-49e2-ab70-3037a75cec7e": {
                "uuids": [
                    "91363e7f-584b-49cc-822c-52c2c01e5928"
                ],
                "occupancy": 1
            },
            "c068d15e-772a-4bcd-aa27-f920b7a4eaa8": {
                "uuids": [
                    "ccfac1dd-b3a5-4afd-9fd9-db11aeb65395"
                ],
                "occupancy": 1
            }
        },
        "total_channels": 3,
        "total_occupancy": 3
    },
    "service": "Presence"
}
```

Since this example is just looking for one specific channel, I did not implement the channels loop and just hardcoded the channel name into the response parsing. Here's the resulting code and will work as is using the `demo/demo` keys, but you should replace with your own pub/sub keys. But you should not expose those keys to the public without first [securing you app with PubNub Access Manager](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/getting-started-guides/pubnub-access-manager).

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var publish_key = 'demo'; // replace with your pub key
        var subscribe_key = 'demo'; // replace with your sub key
        var username = "uuid-" + Date.now()
        // window.location.search.substring(1).split('=');

        pubnub = new PubNub({
            publishKey : publish_key,
            subscribeKey : subscribe_key,
            ssl: true, 
            uuid : username
        });

        pubnub.addListener({
            status: function(statusEvent) {
               console.log("Status event received: ", statusEvent);
            },
            message: function(message) {
               console.log("Message received: ", message);
            },
            presence: function(presenceEvent) {
               console.log("Presence event received: ", presenceEvent);
               // by monitoring join/leave/timeout events,
               //  you can update the user list in realtime
               //  after the initial hereNow call
            }
        });

        // subscribing to channel so that at least 
        // 1 occupant is there when we call hereNow
        pubnub.subscribe({
           channels: ['lupkschat'],
           withPresence: true
        });

    })();
    </script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var updateChannelState = function() {
        pubnub.hereNow({
           channels : ['lupkschat'],
           withPresence: true
        },
        function(status, response){ 
            console.log(status, response);
            // hardcoded with known channel for this simple example
            // best practice would be to loop through all channels
            var channel = response.channels['lupkschat'];
            var uuids = [];

            for (var i=0; i < channel.occupancy; i++) {
               uuids.push(channel.occupants[i].uuid);
            }

            $('#channelStateBar')[0].innerHTML = 'Occupancy : ' 
               + channel.occupancy + '<br>' 
               + 'Users : [' + uuids.join(" | ") + "]";
        });
    };
    </script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>LupkerMusic</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="title">LUPKERMUSIC</h1>
    List of Users
    <div class="channelState" id="channelStateBar"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary updateButton" onclick="updateChannelState()">Update User List</button> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var publish_key = 'demo'; // replace with your pub key
        var subscribe_key = 'demo'; // replace with your sub key
        var username = "uuid-" + Date.now()
        // window.location.search.substring(1).split('=');

        pubnub = new PubNub({
            publishKey : publish_key,
            subscribeKey : subscribe_key,
            ssl: true, 
            uuid : username
        });

        pubnub.addListener({
            status: function(statusEvent) {
               console.log("Status event received: ", statusEvent);
            },
            message: function(message) {
               console.log("Message received: ", message);
            },
            presence: function(presenceEvent) {
               console.log("Presence event received: ", presenceEvent);
               // by monitoring join/leave/timeout events,
               //  you can update the user list in realtime
               //  after the initial hereNow call
            }
        });

        // subscribing to channel so that at least 
        // 1 occupant is there when we call hereNow
        pubnub.subscribe({
           channels: ['lupkschat'],
           withPresence: true
        });

    })();
    </script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var updateChannelState = function() {
        pubnub.hereNow({
           channels : ['lupkschat'],
           withPresence: true
        },
        function(status, response){ 
            console.log(status, response);
            // hardcoded with known channel for this simple example
            // best practice would be to loop through all channels
            var channel = response.channels['lupkschat'];
            var uuids = [];

            for (var i=0; i < channel.occupancy; i++) {
               uuids.push(channel.occupants[i].uuid);
            }

            $('#channelStateBar')[0].innerHTML = 'Occupancy : ' 
               + channel.occupancy + '<br>' 
               + 'Users : [' + uuids.join(" | ") + "]";
        });
    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please leave comments if you have further questions.

Comment: Above code snippet has a bug when you click `Update User List` button. Working on the fix but code works if you run it in it's own file on your system.

Comment: I fixed the Run Code Snippet issue. It was just a mistake with how I created the snippet with Stack Overflow.